# merge 2 object arrays into 1 arays

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some array

```
Array(
[form] => nama_user=&username=&password=
[form_case] => tambah 
)
```

so I want to like this

```
Array( 
[nama_user] =>
[username]  => 
[password]  => 
[form_case] => tambah
)
```

how should I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Split the text based on `&`.
- Run a foreach loop.
- Set all values as key to the array.
- Unset `form` key.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = array(
            'form' => 'nama_user=&username=&password=',
            'form_case' => 'tambah' 
        );

foreach(explode("&",$data['form']) as $key => $value){
    $value = explode("=",$value);
    $data[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}

unset($data['form']);

print_r($data);
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e958e229642dbfe75385eb0ff462a13aa9a6f019